# minio slow read speed for small files

Tags: performance, file, bigdata, minio

i was under the impression that minio is well suited for small file storage and read (https://blog.min.io/minio-optimizes-small-objects/) , i finally migrated my 2 million small text files but the read speed surprisengly slower than directly from the disk ... is there a way to compact/merge those small files ? or is there something that i am doing wrong ...
my usual use case : reading a 10 000 random read files
when it was directly from the disk i average around 120 seconds
i transfered then to a local network solution : it took a round 500-600 seconds to read
now with minio its around 600 seconds
RQ : (
the disk is capable of outputting greater speed but in large files also for minio it works great with large files
)...
do you guys have any idea ... i am really stuck :(

Answer (score -1):

minio was never a good system to deal with that kinda of problem i think u just need to get a faster hardware (drive) ssd should work fine for u

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).